# filtering in magento collection?

Tags: mysql, magento, collections

the following code:

```
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                   array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
                   array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),

            ));
```

creates a query something like:

```
         where  ( someattribute like 'value' OR otherattribute like 'value' )
```

but how could i add an AND condition to this OR conditions? I mean something like this:

```
        where ( (someattribute like 'value' AND someattribute  != 'another value')  OR otherattribute like 'value' )
```

I am using addAttributeToFilter multiple times in the construction of my collection, however, i tried to add the above mentioned condition with the following code:

```
 $collection->getSelect->where( "(someattribute like 'value' AND someattribute  != 'another value')  OR otherattribute like 'value' )"  )
```

but it's not working. Maybe it's not possible to use addAttributeToFilter AS well as where to the same collection?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's working...there was some error in the conditionals i added

so, you can use addAttributeToFilter and also "where" on the same magento collection. Anyway, maybe it will help someone else as well, this solution, but still wondering if you can replicate the above where condition using only addAttributeToFilter...

Answer (score 0):

By definition :

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
               array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
               array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),

        )
```

This is a OR selection to have a AND use :

```
 ->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'))->addAttributeToFilter(array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'))
```